# Self-pinging behaviour inconsistent

Tags: bug, chat, ping

When I attempt to ping myself in chat (`@KennyLau Testing`), it does not work. Also, when I hover over my comment, it does not highlight my previous comment in grey as it would for others.

However, if I try to reply to my message (`:29967544 Testing`), I receive the ping. In addition, when I hover over my comment, it highlights my previous comment in grey as it would for others.

Are we supposed to be able to ping ourselves or not? Please make this consistent.

There are some benefits of being able to ping ourselves, for example replying to yourself can be used to point at the specific previous message that you are commenting on.

Comment: You cannot ping current or future messages.

Comment: [Yes, we can](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29967645#29967645).

Comment: I mean, messages that do not exist at the time of the edit/post.

Comment: Could you make clear which behaviour you would like to see? Currently it sounds like you don't care which aspect is changed as long as it is consistent.

Comment: That is correct. Just make it consistent. I have no idea which behaviour is intended.

Comment: It may not be consistent, but it does make sense.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "Then don't do that..."

Comment: Without defining which solution you want, it initially sounded like you wanted "make @myself ping me with a noise and highlight my previous message", which I can understand being downvoted. Now that you've edited, saying you don't care which is changed means that this downvotable suggestion is still one of the two options you are happy to accept. That's still likely to lead to downvoting (which on meta can just mean "I disagree")

Comment: Also, the discussion in comments about pinging future (unwritten) messages makes this sound like a sandbox experiment with no practical purpose. It might help if you mention in the question that replying to yourself can be used to point at the specific previous message that you are commenting on, for context.

Comment: Pinging yourself and replying to yourself are not the same thing, so why should they behave the same way?

Answer (score 5):

> Are we supposed to be able to ping ourselves or not?

What would be the benefit of that? None. So no, it should not be possible.

> Please make this consistent.

It is. Pinging yourself or another user is something else than replying to a message. There is no need for consistency since they are two separate things.

> There are some benefits of being able to ping ourselves, for example replying to yourself can be used to point at the specific previous message that you are commenting on.

No. There are no benefits of pinging yourself. Replying to a previous message of yourself is, and that is supported.

You make no attempt to explain why this is a bug, so as a feature request, I would say *no*. An added feature like this is useless.

Comment: All correct, maybe worth to mention that for your own messages, you don't get a "reply" icon, though a very popular user script (SOUP, if I'm not wrong) add it so many users have this without even knowing it's not official.